# How to programmatically add an enableWhen condition in my java class -Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

First, I think I have to clarify some points related to my issue:
I want to override a behavior of a button on a RCP project to add a specific treatment. So I did some steps :

1. I created a new fragment over this existing plugin, which I don't have access to.
2. I override the existing handler on my new fragment.
3. I added a fragement.xml, within I defined a new context, the override handler as shown in the code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<fragment>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
        <context id="myContext" name="myContext">
        </context>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
        <handler class="myHandler" commandId="myCommand">
            <enabledWhen>
                <and>
                    <reference definitionId="object_selected">
                    </reference>
                    <reference definitionId="operation_allowed">
                    </reference>
                </and>
            </enabledWhen>
            <activeWhen>
                <with variable="activeContexts">
                </with>
                <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
                    <equals value="myContext">
                    </equals>
                </iterate>
            </activeWhen>
        </handler>
    </extension>
</fragment>
```

But my context is all the time undefined(I don't know why??), so I defined pro-grammatically the context, the override handler and I linked it to myCommand as shown in the following code:

```java
//Define myContext
IContextService contextService = (IContextService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IContextService.class);
Context myContext = contextService.getContext("myContext");

if (!myContext.isDefined()) {
  myContext.define("myContext", "To allow the consumption of my overrided Handler", "org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window");
} 
contextService.activateContext(myContext.getId());

//link handler to myContext

//Command
ICommandService iCommandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
Command myCommand = iCommandService.getCommand("myCommand");

//Handler
IHandlerService   iHandlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
 MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
myCommand.setHandler(handler);

//set activation conditions
if(myContext!= null && contextService.getActiveContextIds().contains(myContext.getId())) {
    iHandlerService.activateHandler("myCommand", myHandler);
    // I'm stuck on this step, i need to know how to declare an enableWhen //condition like: myHandler.setEnabled(evaluationContext);
}
```

Now, I'm stuck on this step : I don't know how to add the enable condition (something like myHandler.setEnabled(evaluationContext))programmatically for my override handler.

Comment: Are you asking how to evaluate that expression programmatically?

Comment: Hello greg-449, Thank you for reply.Yes exactely, I mean that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.eclipse.core.expressions.ExpressionConverter` to convert an XML DOM or an `IConfigurationElement` (from a plug-xml) to an expression that can be evaluated.

```java
ExpressionConverter converter = ExpressionConverter.getDefault();

Expression expression = converter.perform(element);
```

where `element` is either a `IConfigurationElement` or a `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

Once you have the expression you can evaluate it:

```java
EvaluationResult result = expression.evaluate(context);

boolean isEnabled = result == EvaluationResult.TRUE;
```

where `context` is an `IEvaluationContext`

For the context you may be able to use `org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.ExpressionContext`

```java
IEclipseContext eclipseContext = ... current Eclipse context

IEvaluationContext context = new ExpressionContext(eclipseContext);
```

Comment: So I added your Code like that:
String enableCondition = "<enabledWhen>" + 
"<and>" + 
"   <reference definitionId=\"object_selected\">" + 
"   </reference>" + 
"   <reference definitionId=\"operation_allowed\">"+ 
"   </reference>" + 
"</and>" + 
"</enabledWhen>";

Comment: try {
      Document doc = XmlUtils.parseStringToDoc(enableCondition, false);
      ExpressionConverter converter = ExpressionConverter.getDefault();
      Expression expression = converter.perform(doc.getDocumentElement());
      
      EvaluationResult result = expression.evaluate(context);

boolean isEnabled = result == EvaluationResult.TRUE;
      
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } 
   
But I don't know how to get a context??

Have any ideas please?

Comment: Please Greg, I just have modified the description of the issue, please could you have a look to it and also these two comments I added above.

Comment: Maybe use org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.ExpressionContext, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you Greg.So, I use the Eclipse RCP version="3.4", I can't  use Expression Context.Please can you provide me the equivalent of this instruction on the "3.4" version?

Comment: 3.4 is 14 releases and 11 years out of date. I'm not sure what the equivalent was then. Possibly `org.eclipse.core.expressions.EvaluationContext` but I really don't know.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg For your help :) .But it doesn't' work with EvaluationContext, could someone help me? Thank you in advance.